# how to build linux kernel in OpenWrt distribution

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel, openwrt

I make a modification in linux kernel of OpenWrt and then I compile the new (kernel) with command :

> make target/linux/compile V=99

but I don't found the new image under

> build_dir\linux-x86_generic\linux-3.3.8

in order to upgrade the kernel in my OpenWrt running in VM VirtuaBox

how to proceed to get the new kernel and upgrade the Openwrt ?

Comment: In which path have you done your modifications ?. did you try `make world`

Answer (score 0):

I am a bit puzzled by the fact you are looking at the linux-x86 folder since with openWRT you usually cross-compile everytime, or at least I've never used it for not cross compilations.

What are you compiling for ?

You should see a build/$TARGET folder with a linux-x-x directory in it where the linux kernel was compiled.